# Filter r dataframe for row and column names by value

Tags: r

A follow up question:
I am building a dynamic UI in shiny and want that possible choices are depending on previous choices.
I filter the dataset

```
df <- read.table(text = "  a b c d
                 X 1 1 1 0 
                 Y 1 0 0 0 
                 Z 0 1 0 0 ", header = T)
```

I can create a list of all row and colum names with at leat one element >0

```
col <- names(which(colSums(df == 1) > 0))
row <- names(which(rowSums(df == 1) > 0))
col_row <- c(col,row)
```

Now the user selects on element of col_row. The next thing I want to do is to read the row/column names for a specific choice.

2 cases

1. User selects `a`. Now I want to read from df$a all **row names** with
   the value 1 in df$a
2. User selects `X` . I want all **column names** with the value 1 in row `X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but works.

```
df <- read.table(text = "  a b c d
                 X 1 1 1 0 
                 Y 1 0 0 0 
                 Z 0 1 0 0 ", header = T)

#   a b c d
# X 1 1 1 0
# Y 1 0 0 0
# Z 0 1 0 0

col <- names(which(colSums(df == 1) > 0))
row <- names(which(rowSums(df == 1) > 0))

choice <- "c"

if (choice %in% col) {
  rownames(df[df[choice] == 1, ])
} else if (choice %in% row) {
  colnames(df)[df[choice, ] == 1]
}
```

Comment: What is `library(dplyr)` for in this case?

Comment: It is indeed a mistake, I've used `%in%` and kinda unconsciously loaded `dplyr` as if it was `%>%`. Thanks for pointing this!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
row.names(df)[df[,col_row=="a"]==1]
#[1] "X" "Y"

d1 <- df[intersect(col_row, "X"),]==1
colnames(d1)[d1]
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: @user2963882  It is the object you created `col_row <- c(col,row)`.  Please check your code

Comment: One questions. D1 returns not the column names but rather a new dataframe with TRUE /FALSE. How can I tweek the code that it only returns column names.

Comment: @user2963882  It returns TRUE/FALSE with names because we did the `== 1`.  In the next line, it does return the column names. Are you saying that you want it in one line?